# Check types of query or mutation fields in a custom client parser

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

Using a custom client to make graphQL requests in the browser, I would like to build a custom parser.  I would like to use Sanctuary.js Maybe types for Nullable field types.  What I need to know is how can the client know if a certain field is Nullable or NonNullable automatically.  Would I need to have access to the schema in the client to be able to handle that?

```
function myCustomParser (data, ...otherArgs) {
  // ...custom parsing on a field level
};

fetch ('/graphql', {
  method: 'post'
  body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
}).then (res => res.json ()).then (data => {
  return myCustomParser (data);
});
```

I'd like to return Sanctuary.js Maybe types for Nullable Fields.  The parser needs to know if a certain field is defined as a Nullable or Non Nullable type.  I can handle the Sanctuary.js part, I'm just not sure how to do the above using GraphQL.js.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have to know the schema on the client side for you to dynamically wrap these values into Sanctuary Maybe values. Sanctuary Maybe values are objects and need to wrap not only the null values but also the non-null values. This is not possible on the value level without information about the schema.

Having schema information at runtime is as well not ideal because the Schema might be really big. The way many strictly typed languages do that is compiling the query. At build time they then have the schema available.
Check out [Elm GraphQL](https://github.com/dillonkearns/elm-graphql) for a good example.